# TypeScript - типизация при обращении к объектам через квадратные скобки

Tags: javascript, typescript, типы

Моё почтение!

Есть в json'e массив с объектами с интерфейсом:

```js
const data: IData[] = [
    {
        "name": "Телеграм",
        "iconName": "telegram"
    },
    {
        "name": "Телефон",
        "iconName": "phone"
    },
    {
        "name": "Почта",
        "iconName": "email"
    },
]

interface IData {
    name: string;
    iconName: string;
}
```

А так же объект, в котором хранятся компоненты с иконками:

```js
const icons: IIcons = {
        phone: <PhoneSvg />,
        telegram: <TelegramSvg/>,
        email: <EmailSvg />,
    }

interface IIconns {
    phone: JSX.Element;
    telegram: JSX.Element;
    email: JSX.Element;
}
```

По первому прохожусь мапом, вытаскиваю из него iconName и использую для того, чтобы получить компонент с svg в нужном месте:

```js
data.map(contact => (
    //...
        <SvgIcon 
            color="primary" 
            viewBox="0 0 15 15" 
            sx={{width: "15px", height: "15px"}}
        >
            {icons[contact.iconName]}
        </SvgIcon>
    // ...
))
```

Всё работает, но TS ругается, так что встаёт вопрос - как протипизировать конструкцию с квадратными скобками, чтобы ему всё нравилось? Просьба ответить как можно подробнее, а то у меня с TS'ом пока натянутые отношения.

На данный момент выдаёт ошибку:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IIconns'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IIconns'.ts(7053)
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо добавить индекс для интерфейса, что бы ТС понимал, что ключи это строки и значения у них JSX.Element

```
interface IIconns {
    [key: string]: JSX.Element; // Вот такой
    phone: JSX.Element;
    telegram: JSX.Element;
    email: JSX.Element;
}
```

или

```
interface IIconns {
    [index: string]: JSX.Element; // Вот такой
    phone: JSX.Element;
    telegram: JSX.Element;
    email: JSX.Element;
}
```

что одно и то же

Comment: ну не, индексатор полностью убивает смысл перечисления остальных полей - потому что в него можно что угодно передать

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы typescript не ругался, достаточно указать, что поле `iconName` может принимать только значения, которые есть в ключах IIconns.

Для этого можно воспользоваться [оператором `keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html)

```
interface IData {
    name: string;
    iconName: keyof IIcons;
}
```

[***Playground Link***](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=27&pln=18&pc=15#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggXDAkgESQg2gXRgF4ZcBYAKBmpgG9KbGYAiMBAWwFNm1nAiEECsIIG4QAYGYQQAIggBhBAPCDMANAybVmAS1BgAch268onADacA5gCcOzRdQC+CqjXp2lrbTxaCRgERBAfCCBeEHmWmVXUtLldmAAcAC3BuAJsAhyVlNlDeQHwQL0BxEEAhEEl-R0C1cBCdFk52BBV9CwL4inxKShUwPRMAMwRgTgxsZDoAlM40aBNmowBuAKLNbTQAa04ATxA2jHR1CEmKK0aKDdhpiDR0dfAIYn6CxiiYtAByAEY72ySYPUNTDnuAJmeAxnKlX09wAzH9artmq0Ol01htLtdomAhjAEGBFltGO9jGZ2Gg0RiAoCqvj0VsdhRKIhkAA6CrhAAU6mQwFgRAAfDAGf8kodcMzOlAadMSg0KABKcVAA)